# Find a value based on the minimum in a group SQL

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to find the names of the youngest person within a group of rankings. Everything is in the table Person, with fields PName(various), PAge(various), PRanking(0-3). I wish to find the name of the youngest person in each ranking group (0-3). Therefore, if there is a person with a ranking in each group, the query will return 4 names (the youngest person in each ranking).

My approach so far is:

```
SELECT PName
FROM Person
WHERE PAge = MIN(PAge)
GROUPBY PRanking
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What's the expected result in case of a tie? (Two persons with the same min age.)

Comment: `pranking`and `page` - funny column names for a `person` table :-)

Comment: On a sidenote: I hope this is just an example in order to illustrate the problem. With an age column you'd have to update the table daily to have it up-to-date. One would of course store the birthday instead.

Comment: I need to restate....I want to find the NAMES of the youngest people for each group within groups of rankings. Each person in the datatable has a ranking of 0-3....I want to find the name of the youngest person in each ranking group.

Answer (score 2):

You could join the subselect  for  the min age

```
   select P.PName from Person P
    inner join (
    SELECT ranking, min(age)  min_age
    FROM Person
    GROUP BY PRanking 
    ) t on t.ranking  = p.ranking  and t.min_age = p.age
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a `group by` problem.  This is a filtering problem.  So, think `where`, not `group by`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Person p
WHERE PAge = (SELECT MIN(p2.PAge) FROM Person p2 WHERE p2.PRanking = p.PRanking);
```

With an index on `Person(Pranking, PAge)`, this is likely to have performance as least as good as any other method.

Comment: OP seeks min age of multiple people across several groups -> `GROUP BY name, ranking` so there's an additional factor this query doesn't consider

Comment: @CaiusJard . . . Of course it does.  That is what the correlation clause does.

Comment: My bad, for some reason I didn't see that part!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Person p 
WHERE p.PAge,p.Pgroup in =
  (SELECT MIN(p2.PAge), p2.Pranking FROM Person P2 Group by P2.pranking);
```

Comment: The `WHERE (a,b) IN (SELECT x,z FROM...)` won't work in all databases.. Also, please fix the syntax errors in your code

Comment: Yes  can use the subselect in join